# For some $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and $\{a,b\}\in\Bbb{Z}$, prove or deny: $\lfloor\frac{a+x}b\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{a+\lfloor x\rfloor}b\right\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> For some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\{ a,b \} \in \mathbb{Z}$, prove or deny that:
>
> $$\left\lfloor \frac {a+x}b\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac {a+\lfloor x\rfloor}b\right\rfloor$$

I'm trying to use $m−1<\lfloor m \rfloor \leq m$.

I've tried substituting $x-1$ and into each side but I don't see a guaranteed proof or denial

Comment: Consider $b=-1$. (you need $b>0$ for this to be true)

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155068/i-cant-seem-to-prove-propositions-involving-floor-ceiling-function-and-the-like/4156205#4156205) here. I have answered a question far more general than what is being asked, and we can think about closure as a duplicate.

Comment: What is the context that is leading you to ask this question and other recent things like solving $x^2-6x+8 \equiv 0 \bmod 105$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple proof. Note that $a = kb + r$, and substitute this in
$\lfloor \frac{kb + r + x}{b} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{r + x}{b} \rfloor$

Obviously, comparing $\lfloor \frac{r + x}{b} \rfloor$ and $\lfloor \frac{r + \lfloor x \rfloor}{b} \rfloor$, it is obvious that the statement is always true, as both $r + x$ and $r + \lfloor x \rfloor$ share the same integer part, so division by another integer will return the same quotient always.

A few adjustments need to be made to the question. Namely, $b > 0$.

Comment: Indeed. Rounding $x$ down to the nearest integer can never cause $a+x$ to drop _past_ an integer multiple of $b$, which is where the value of $\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\cdots}{b} \Bigr\rfloor$ would change.

Comment: Well put @Troposphere